# How to use try-catch without stopping the code execution

Tags: java

I have this snipped code:

```
   try{
        JAXB.xmlJavaConverter(clientCommand);
    } catch (Exception e){
        nServerFifo.add(clientCommand);
    }
```

I want to call remote Java method `JAXB.xmlJavaConverter(clientCommand);`. If this some reason fails I want to insert the data into Buffer `nServerFifo.add(clientCommand);`. How I can do this without stopping the code execution. I'm sure that I must replace `Exception e` with something else but I'm not sure what type of exeption I need without sopping the code execution.

Comment: What do you mean by "stopping code execution"? try/catch doesn't stop any execution. It's just a flow-control construct.

Comment: Try/catch doesn't stop code execution. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you catch `Exception`, the `catch` block will be entered for *any* exception.

Your existing code should work.

If you *only* want to enter the `catch` block for a specific type of Exception (which your question does not seem to imply), you would write

```
catch (MoreSpecificExceptionType e)
```

If you did do that,

```
nServerFifo.add(clientCommand);
```

would be executed only if the code in the `try` block throws `MoreSpecificException`.